# Objective-C setHidden for a group of objects

Tags: objective-c, object, button, checkbox, textbox

In my project I´m using setHidden for one object at a time at the moment.
Now I´m in a situation that I have several sets of objects which I want to hide or show depending on the situation.

I´m thinking of naming the objects like checkBox01, checkBox02, checkBox03 and so forth.
I wonder if it is possible to hide/show them all together with one call?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `IBOutletCollection`, and use `makeObjectsPerformSelector` on it.

More on `IBOutletCollection`: http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

Comment: Mmh, I came out with grouping my objects using boxes. But I didn't get IBOutletCollection when assigning the box. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Boxes? What do you mean, you put all your buttons in a single `UIView`?

Comment: The way you write it it sounds weird. But there are only a few buttons (up to five) in a box. And making the box invisible makes also the contents invisible. Works like a charm. And I don't have to change code if I add a new object. Just put it into the proper box.

Comment: I hope my comment didn't sound unfriendly, that was not my intention :) If so I'm sorry. I'm not very experienced with ObjC. Is it wrong to group buttons in boxes? I looked into the documentation and didn't find any comments on that. Btw. I'm not using UIView for grouping but NSBox. I'm on MacOSX.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. I didn't understand you were on desktop rather than on mobile. It's OK to group buttons in `NSBox`es, it's just that IBOutletCollection are more flexible, you can refer to each button programmatically without having to define a `tag` for each of them: you use `[collection objectAtIndex:42]` rather than `[box viewWithTag:42]`, which is faster (no need to loop through the subviews array).